# how to break a time range into monthly queries?

Tags: r, lubridate, purrr

Consider this simple example

```
bogus <- function(start_time, end_time){
  print(paste('hey this starts on', start_time, 'until', end_time))
}

start_time <- ymd('2018-01-01')
end_time <- ymd('2018-05-01')

> bogus(start_time, end_time)
[1] "hey this starts on 2018-01-01 until 2018-05-01"
```

Unfortunately, doing so with a long time range does not work with my real-life `bogus`  function, so I need to break my original time range into monthly pieces.

In other words the first call would be `bogus(ymd('2018-01-01'), ymd('2018-01-31'))`, the second one `bogus(ymd('2018-02-01'), ymd('2018-02-28'))`, etc.

Is there a simple way to do using `purrr` and `lubridate`?
Thanks

Comment: Your function doesn't `return` anything. How will you combine it into a dataframe?

Comment: yeah it does not really matter, I know how to combine them. let me change the wording

Comment: the difficult part is breaking down the query into multiple sub-queries

Comment: To clarify, you want to get a start time and end time, then break that into a sequence of one month chunks, and then vectorize through that sequence for your function? Or do you want the function itself to do the breaking?

Comment: thanks. yes, from a start and end time I would like to get a sequence of one month time ranges so that I can call `bogus` sequentially. something that ends up doing `list(start_col = c(ymd('2018-01-01'), ymd('2018-02-01')), end_col = ymd('2018-02-01'), ymd('2018-02-28')) %>% map2df(., bogus(.x, .y))`

Comment: but the issue is getting the first list

Comment: base: `seq.Date(start_time,end_time,by="1 month")`. Result: `[1] "2018-01-01" "2018-02-01" "2018-03-01" "2018-04-01" "2018-05-01"`

Comment: And then do this for your endcol: `endcol<-seq.Date(start_time,end_time,by="1 month")-days(1)` which will give you `[1] "2017-12-31" "2018-01-31" "2018-02-28" "2018-03-31" "2018-04-30"`

Comment: pretty nice indeed! can you post that? I wonder if there is the `lubridate` equivalent here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With base:

```
seqdate<-seq.Date(start_time,end_time,by="1 month")
dateranges<-data.frame(start.dates=seqdate[1:length(seqdate)-1], 
  end.dates=seqdate[2:length(seqdate)]-1)

  start.dates  end.dates
1  2018-01-01 2018-01-31
2  2018-02-01 2018-02-28
3  2018-03-01 2018-03-31
4  2018-04-01 2018-04-30
```

Answer (score 4):

Are you looking for something like:

```
library(lubridate)

seq_dates <- seq(start_time, end_time - 1, by = "month")

lapply(seq_dates, function(x) print(paste('hey this starts on', x, 'until', ceiling_date(x, unit = "month") - 1)))
```

You could also do a short bogus function like:

```
bogus <- function(start_var, end_var) {

 require(lubridate)

 seq_dates <- seq(as.Date(start_var), as.Date(end_var) - 1, by = "month")

 printed_statement <- lapply(seq_dates, function(x) paste('hey this starts on', x, 'until', ceiling_date(x, unit = "month") - 1))

 for (i in printed_statement) { print(i) }

}
```

And call it like:

```
bogus("2018-01-01", "2018-05-01")
```

Output:

```
[1] "hey this starts on 2018-01-01 until 2018-01-31"
[1] "hey this starts on 2018-02-01 until 2018-02-28"
[1] "hey this starts on 2018-03-01 until 2018-03-31"
[1] "hey this starts on 2018-04-01 until 2018-04-30"
```

This way you can just give minimum start and maximum end date and get everything in-between.